# Integer cannot be converted to comparable

Tags: java, integer, compare, incompatibletypeerror

So im getting this error when I run this code:
Integer[] cannot be converted to Comparable[] bubble(list);

I thought the integer class implemented the comparable interface. Why am I getting this error? Thanks!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class test
{
public static void main(String [] args) {
Integer [] list={8,1,7,2,6,3,5,4};

bubble(list);
}
private static void swap(Object [] list, int x, int y)
{
    Object temp=list[x];
    list[x]=list[y];
    list[y]=temp;
}

public static void bubble(Comparable [] list)
{
    boolean done=false;
    while(!done)
    {
        done=true;
        for(int i=0; i+1<list.length; i++)
            if(list[i].compareTo(list[i+1])>0)
            { swap(list,i,i+1); done=false; }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: An `Integer` is `Comparable`. Arrays are their own type, and an array of integers isn't an array of comparables. Use a collection or an `Integer[]` (which is not an `int[]` either).

Comment: Your code works fine for me.